# Como percorrer um array e fazer um filtro para juntar itens da mesma categoria

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Estou criando um aplicativo com Ionic 6 para fazer a lista de mercado, e gostaria de categorizar os itens para juntar todos no mesmo card quando houver algum item da mesma categoria que ele já adicionado. Estou com dificuldade para realizar essa junção, sempre que adicionar um novo item preciso validar se a categoria dele já não está sendo exibida, caso sim, quero juntar o novo item com os adicionados, caso não esteja é só criar um novo card e jogar o item. Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer?

Meu arquivo .ts

```
// Funcao que busco os itens cadastrados e atualizo a lista de exibição 
  public searchLista() {
    this.iEditar = false;
    this.iListaMercado = [];

    this.cListaMercadoService.listaMercadoAcoes('GET', [])
      .then(($return: any) => {
        for (let wItens of $return.itens_mercado) {

          if (wItens.categoria == '') {
            wItens.categoria = 'Diversos';
          }

          this.iListaMercado.push({
            categoria: wItens.categoria,
            itens: [{
              id: wItens.id,
              produto: wItens.produto,
              quantidade: wItens.quantidade,
              unid_medida: wItens.unid_medida,
              class: '',
              selecionado: false
            }]
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

Interface que estou usando para tipar o iListaMercado

```
export interface ListaMercado {
  categoria: string,
  itens: Array<Itens>
}

// Interface para tipagem do array de itens
interface Itens {
  id?: number,
  produto: string,
  quantidade: number,
  unid_medida: string,
  class: string,
  selecionado: boolean
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Para facilitar a inclusão dos ítens de forma mais simples nos respectivos `Cards`. Crie um array para cada `Categoria` e na hora de inserir o produto faça a inserção direto no seu devido array/categoria. No arquivo `HTML` crie um Card para cada categoria e exiba apenas os Cards que possuem conteúdo usando *ngIf.
Por exemplo:

```
<div *ngIf="wItens.categoria==='Diversos' && itens_mercado.length>0"> 
    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of itens_mercado">
        <span> {{ item.name }} </span>
        <span> {{ item.peso }} </span>
    </ion-card>
</div>
```